Sonar Error on iframe: Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners
I have this code:
export function Frame({ url }: Readonly<FrameProps>) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const handleLoadedIframe = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
      {isLoading && <Spinner .../>}
      <iframe
        title="xxx"
        className="yyy"
        style={{ display: isLoading ? 'none' : 'block' }}
        src={url}
        onLoad={handleLoadedIframe}
      />
  );
}

On the iframe I have this sonar error:
Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners.
The problem comes from the onLoad listener. I understand the problem when it is an onClick listener on a div or a span but not for this case. I didn't find any answers with the iframe element.
